# Getting Undefined property ERROR in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

When I print the value as dd() like

```
{{dd(json_decode($val->receiver_message)[0]->name)}}
```

I got the output. but when I am pass this inside div it gives error

```
 ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Undefined property: stdClass::$name
```

Comment: what's `{{dd(json_decode($val->receiver_message)[0])}}`?

Comment: how are you passing the value to display it in the div?

Comment: No i am getting the result from {{dd(json_decode($val->receiver_message)[0]->name)}} only.

Comment: @brownkid <div class="comment-content">
                                                                 {{json_decode($val->receiver_message[0]->name)}}
                                                            </div>

Comment: @Bandana Sahu can you please share the full function code so, we can help you.

Comment: @brownkid i have one string "[{"id":"","name":"abc new","message":"Admin welcomes you to join project abc new."}]" i want name from that string. In dd it print the result but when i put inside the div it wont.